# Filebeat - Failed to publish events caused by: read tcp x.x.x.x:36196->x.x.x.x:5045: i/o timeout

Tags: logstash, filebeat

Hi i'm running into a problem while sending logs via filebeat to logstash:
In short - Can't see logs in kibana - when tailing the filebeat log I see a lot of these:
ERROR   logstash/async.go:235   Failed to publish events caused by: read tcp x.x.x.x:36246->y.y,y.y:5045: i/o timeout (while y.y,y.y is logstash address and 5045 is the open beat port)

More details:
I have ~60 machines with filebeat 6.1.1 installed and one logstash machine with logstash 6.2.3 installed.
Some filebeats successfully sends their logs while some throws the error I mentioned above.
those non-errors filebeats sends old logs - means I can see in logstash debug logs that some logs timestamp are 2 or 3 days ago

Logstash usage memory is 35% and cpu usage near 75% on peaks,
in netstat -tupn output in the filebeat machines I can see that the established connections to logstash from filebeat.

Can someone help me find the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like logstash performance issue. Cpu usage its probabbly too high  Memory could be more. increase the minimum (Xms) and maximum (Xmx) heap allocation size to =[Total amount in the host - 1], (live 1 G to the Os) and set it equals (xms=xmx)

Also you can run another logstash instance and balance the filebeat output to these 2 and see what happen.

More things to consider:

**Performance Checklist**

Check the performance of input sources and output destinations:

Logstash is only as fast as the services it connects to. Logstash can only consume and produce data as fast as its input and output destinations can!
Check system statistics:

**CPU**

Note whether the CPU is being heavily used. On Linux/Unix, you can run top -H to see process statistics broken out by thread, as well as total CPU statistics.
If CPU usage is high, skip forward to the section about checking the JVM heap and then read the section about tuning Logstash worker settings.

**Memory**

Be aware of the fact that Logstash runs on the Java VM. This means that Logstash will always use the maximum amount of memory you allocate to it.
Look for other applications that use large amounts of memory and may be causing Logstash to swap to disk. This can happen if the total memory used by applications exceeds physical memory.
I/O Utilization

**Monitor disk I/O to check for disk saturation.**

Disk saturation can happen if you’re using Logstash plugins (such as the file output) that may saturate your storage.
Disk saturation can also happen if you’re encountering a lot of errors that force Logstash to generate large error logs.
On Linux, you can use iostat, dstat, or something similar to monitor disk I/O.

**Monitor network I/O for network saturation.**

Network saturation can happen if you’re using inputs/outputs that perform a lot of network operations.
On Linux, you can use a tool like dstat or iftop to monitor your network.
Check the JVM heap:

Often times CPU utilization can go through the roof if the heap size is too low, resulting in the JVM constantly garbage collecting.
A quick way to check for this issue is to double the heap size and see if performance improves. Do not increase the heap size past the amount of physical memory. Leave at least 1GB free for the OS and other processes.
You can make more accurate measurements of the JVM heap by using either the jmap command line utility distributed with Java or by using VisualVM. For more info, see Profiling the Heapedit.

Always make sure to set the minimum (Xms) and maximum (Xmx) heap allocation size to the same value to prevent the heap from resizing at runtime, which is a very costly process.
Tune Logstash worker settings:

Begin by scaling up the number of pipeline workers by using the -w flag. This will increase the number of threads available for filters and outputs. It is safe to scale this up to a multiple of CPU cores, if need be, as the threads can become idle on I/O.
You may also tune the output batch size. For many outputs, such as the Elasticsearch output, this setting will correspond to the size of I/O operations. In the case of the Elasticsearch output, this setting corresponds to the batch size.

[More info here.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/6.0/performance-troubleshooting.html#_performance_checklist)